# unable to cast com object (msxml) to system.xml object

Tags: c#, vbscript, msxml, system.xml

i want to upgrade my project from msxml6 to system.xml. The msxml component is coming from vb script using interfaces as type object(i.e com_object). Now the problem is when i try to cast this com object to the System.xml component it throwing en exception. Can anybody help me on this. any suggestions?

Comment: That's just not possible.

Comment: Can i get any alternatives?